# typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars incorrectly shows assigned a value but never used

Tags: typescript, eslint

Ever since I upgraded @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin and @typescript-eslint/parser to version ^4.26.0, I'm now getting `'xxxxx' is assigned a value but never used. eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars` warnings in my editor. For instance:

```
export default function TransactionsScreen({ navigation }: ClientWalletNavigation) {
  const user = useStore((state) => state.user);
  const { data, loading, error, refetch } = useQuery(getTransactions, {
    variables: { uid: user?.id, customer: user!.stripe?.customer },
  });
```

In the above example it shows a warning for `user` with `'user' is assigned a value but never used` - obviously it is used.
Any ideas?

Comment: You might have better luck opening an issue at their official repo.

Comment: You may be right. Planning to.